# Conformal mapping into a unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

$T$ is the upper half of the unit disc $U$. What is the conformal mapping $f$ of $T$ onto $U$ that transforms $\{-1,0,1\}$ to $\{-1,-i,1\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First map $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ to $\{0, 1, \infty\}$ by the transform
$$-\frac{z+1}{z-1}.$$
This maps $T$ to the first quadrant of $\mathbb{C}$. By squaring
$$\left(-\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^2$$
we get the whole upper half plane. Using Cayley transform we get the unit circle $U$:
$$\frac{(z+1)^2 - i(z-1)^2}{(z+1)^2 + i(z-1)^2}.$$
By direct computation we check that $\{-1,0,1\}$ is actually sent to $\{-1,-i,1\}$, so the orientation is correct. (Otherwise we could rotate the result by multiplying by $e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta$.)